# How to find overlap between two integer series in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two columns as follows:

```
start   end     id
120      125    1
1        13     2
14       17     3 
100      121    4
99       100    5
2         6     6
```

As you can see there is an overlap between `id=4 and id=5`, `id=1 and id=4`, `id=6 and id=2`

I should note that `start` is always smaller or equals to `end`.

How can I find these overlaps using SQL?
Basically I want the result to be:

```
1
2
4
5
6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would get any id that overlaps with another using `exists`:

```
select id
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.start <= t.end and t2.end >= t.start and t2.id <> t.id
             );
```

I think it would be more useful to see the *pairs* of ids that overlap:

```
select t.id, t2.id
from t t join
     t t2
     on t2.start <= t.end and t2.end >= t.start and t.id < t2.id;
```

EDIT:

Here is a demonstration of it working:

```
with t (start, "end", id) as (
     values (120, 125, 1),
            (1, 13, 2),
            (14, 17, 3),
            (100, 121, 4),
            (99, 100, 5),
            (2, 6, 6)
    )
select id
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.start <= t."end" and t2."end" >= t.start and t.id <> t2.id
             );
```

Comment: It has a major flaw ... it checks only from id to higher ids.... meaning that if I add where condition to a specific id example t.id=4... it won't compare it with id=2 for example.

Comment: the `exists` solution is not correct, it gives out also `id=3` which does not overlap any other serie.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct d1.id
    --, d2.id id_overlap -- if you want to see the overlapping serie id uncomment this line
from t d1
join t d2 on 
    (d1.id <> d2.id) and 
    (   
    (d1.start between d2.start and d2.[end] or d1.[end] between d2.start and d2.[end])
    or
    (d2.start between d1.start and d1.[end] or d2.[end] between d1.start and d1.[end])
    )
```